# parsing an XML file and filling with some data from another file

Tags: xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have a XML file which contains some tags and values.

```
<component id="system.core0.icache" name="icache">
    <param name="icache_config" value="65536,64,2,1,1,2,64,0"/>
    <stat name="read_accesses" value="526692.38"/> 
    <stat name="read_misses" value="2646.34"/>                                 
        <stat name="conflicts" value="2404.67"/>
</component>
<component id="system.core0.dcache" name="dcache">
    <param name="dcache_config" value="65536,64,2,1,1,2,64,0"/>
    <stat name="read_accesses" value="326692.38"/> 
    <stat name="read_misses" value="1646.34"/>                                 
        <stat name="conflicts" value="4404.67"/>
</component>
```

In another file, I have the values in another format. For example

```
 L1D:size 65536
 L1I:size 65536
 L1D:access 526692.38
 L1D:miss 2646.34
 L1D:conflict 2404.67
 L1I:access 326692.38
 L1I:miss 1646.34
 L1I:conflict 4404.67
```

What I want to do is the write a parser that based on a dictionary, copy the values from stat files to the XML file. For example

```
 L1D:size   ->   component.id = "system.core0.dcache" , fill the first value of param "dcache_config"

 L1I:access ->   component.id = "system.core0.icache" , fill the stat value of "read_accesses"
```

I have searched but it seems that parsing an XML file means extracting the values from the XML file. But I don't want that.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

sounds like a solution for a SAX parser.

```
while next element
    compare attributes and content
    if necessary then replace
    output
end
```

Ruby or Perl would come to mind as tools.